# How to use two forms in the Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
var getLoginpasssystem = function(getPassForgotSystem,getLoginCheckSystem){
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#login' || '#lostpasswordform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://www.virtuelles-museum.com.udev/spielelogin/logsystem.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                var data = JSON.parse(response);

                if (data.success == "accepted") {
                    document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = 'Herzlich Willkommen';

                    // location.href = 'index.php';
                } else {
                    alert('Ungültige Email oder Password!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
}
```

The question is how to use two forms in one request with ajax. In this code I used `||`, but it doesn't work. I mean the `#login` form works well but the `#lostpasswordform` doesn't work. When I click on the button it reloads the page instead of giving an alert.

Comment: Joe Z, Thanks it worked well !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is the way you do your jQuery selection. Selecting multiple elements is done like this: `$( "div, span, p.myClass" )`

In other words it should work if you replace `$('#login' || '#lostpasswordform')` with `$('#login, #lostpasswordform')`

You can read more in detail about this in the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

elector be used to select multiple elements.  $("#login,#lostpasswordform").submit()

Use below code :

```
var getLoginpasssystem = function(getPassForgotSystem,getLoginCheckSystem){
$(document).ready(function() { 
        
    $("#login,#lostpasswordform").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'http://www.virtuelles-museum.com.udev/spielelogin/logsystem.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response) {
                var data = JSON.parse(response);

                if (data.success == "accepted") {
                    document.getElementById('inner').innerHTML = 'Herzlich Willkommen';

                    // location.href = 'index.php';
                } else {
                    alert('Ungültige Email oder Password!');
                }
            }
        });
    });
})
}
```